# Reality Composer and dealing with multiple surfaces

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I want to know if there is a way for the scenes that gets exported from the reality composer to deal with multiple surfaces in the real world.

So for example, if we create a scene with a ball that applies a force on the x axis when we touch the ball. I would expect when the scene added on top of a table if the ball gets out of bounds of the table the ball should fall. Which is not happening, the scene is working on one surface only.

Am I missing something or Reality Composer does not support complex scenarios ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Reality Composer a grid simultaneously performs two important roles:

- a hidden infinite collision plane
- an infinite shadows' catcher

If you want any complex dynamics to occur – alas, at the moment it's possible only **above the grid** and **on the grid** (in case you haven't turned the grid off).
Hence, in that sense, now Reality Composer doesn't support complex collision scenarios.

But as a consolation prize, you can load multiple scenes from `.rcproject`:

```
@IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if counter % 2 == 0 {
        let sceneElements_04 = try! myScenes.loadScene_04()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneElements_04)
    } else if counter >= 10 {
        let sceneElements_25 = try! myScenes.loadScene_25()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneElements_25)
    } else {
        let sceneElements_12 = try! myScenes.loadScene_12()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneElements_12)
}
```